# Can I detect if facebook share browser was closed?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

so I have facebook share function and I have 2 pop ups when facebook share was successful or not, but when I close facebook share browser before I push share button close the window well share is unsuccessful but I dont want to get that pop up. so I figured if there is a chance I can catch if the window was closed. 
thanks

Comment: The dialog itself would give the user feedback, if something went wrong - so what would you need this for? (Hope you are aware that you are not allowed to reward people for sharing in any way.)

Comment: If you have a reference to new window created by `window.open()` you can use an interval to check for `closed`. I don't think there is any event you can listen for

Comment: @misorude When share is successful pop up shows up like "your share was successful" and if it is unsuccessful pop up shows up too. but when you close share window before you share it pop us still shows up that it was unsuccessful I want to restrain that and wont show any pop up if the window was closed. No rewards :)

Comment: so what´s the point, you only need this to show some additional popup with the information that it was shared or not? users know that anyway.

Comment: What do you mean with "No rewards"?

Comment: @luschn I just need it man

Comment: in order to answer in a serious way, you will have to tell us what you want to achieve. "i just need it" is not really a use case we can work with, maybe what you want to achieve is not even allowed - wouldn´t you want to know?

Comment: @luschn I would like to catch if it is possible closing of the facebook share window  . I have 2 pop ups after successful and unsuccessful share (It not my idea people just told me to DO it so I do) but I dont want to get that popup if a person closed share window before shearing it. Is it clear?

Comment: we know that, but WHY exactly do you need the popup? without any functionality, this does not really make sense. tell the people who want this, that it´s not possible ;)
again, if people want to share something and the popup closes, they usually know that it got shared. there´s really no point in adding a senseless additional popup just to tell users what they know anyway.

Comment: @luschn yeah I know but what you gonna do if they wanna they wanna :))) Thanks